# Control key stuck but not physically (Lenovo T420)

Tags: thinkpad

A [Lenovo T420 laptop](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t420_t420i_hmm.pdf) worked fine until today.  Now it thinks that the control key is pressed down. When I press the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button it inputs `{`. Space doesn't work and many other keys. I tried booting from a Linux USB but the problem persists. I've also tried switching the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and the <kbd>FN</kbd> key from the BIOS and still nothing. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Try and external keyboard, If it works OK, you probably need to replace your laptop's keyboard.

Comment: In all likelihood the keyboard is defective or has a loose connection or the motherboard itself is defective.

Comment: External keyboards do work fine, do you think it might be a short ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the keyboard is easy; see pages 77-80 of its [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t420_t420i_hmm.pdf).

Remove the keyboard and see if you find anything jamming in the switch area under the key cap. If so, a small paperclip can be bent to fish it out.

Unplugging and replugging the keyboard can also solve this problem.

If there's no foreign object, US English layout keyboards are named FRU 45N2071, FRU 45N2141, and FRU 45N2211 and sell for $19-37 (used-new) on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CJ1ZH56). Other keyboards are listed on page 160 of that manual.

I recently bought a rebuilt T420 for $150 at Fry's Electronics, so the cost of a repair tech should be weighed against that; really, it is an easy task, and Lenovo gives you the best manuals of any laptop maker to help.